# duplicate data being generated when different parameters are used

Tags: python, function

Ive got two functions that take the first one is a 2D curve generator it has 7 parameters and works just fine the second function is largely based upon the first function but its works in 3D instead however its not working as if i generate two different curves using the 3D function they come out the same when they should be coming out different. ill give an example :

```py
curve_1 = build_curve_3D(0,10,10,2,4,6,5,8,9,10)
curve_2 = build_curve_3D(5,7,2,19,15,12,67,9,2,10)
```

This should return two sets of 3 list all contaning unique points but this is the output for this example

```py
>>> print(curve_1)
([5, 6.400000000000005, 9.879999999999983, 14.03999999999999, 18.880000000000006, 24.4, 30.59999999999995, 37.48, 45.0399999999999, 53.280000000000136, 67], [7, 7.800000000000003, 9.119999999999996, 10.159999999999997, 10.92, 11.400000000000004, 11.6, 11.519999999999996, 11.160000000000007, 10.51999999999998, 9], [2, 3.0, 4.6, 5.800000000000002, 6.600000000000001, 7.0, 7.0, 6.6000000000000005, 5.8000000000000025, 4.6000000000000005, 2])
>>> print(curve_2)
([5, 6.400000000000005, 9.879999999999983, 14.03999999999999, 18.880000000000006, 24.4, 30.59999999999995, 37.48, 45.0399999999999, 53.280000000000136, 67], [7, 7.800000000000003, 9.119999999999996, 10.159999999999997, 10.92, 11.400000000000004, 11.6, 11.519999999999996, 11.160000000000007, 10.51999999999998, 9], [2, 3.0, 4.6, 5.800000000000002, 6.600000000000001, 7.0, 7.0, 6.6000000000000005, 5.8000000000000025, 4.6000000000000005, 2])
```

as you can see these two separate curves have yielded the same result for some reason so ill post all the code so its easy to compare the two function and hopefully fix the problem.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
global curve_x , curve_y , curve_z

curve_x, curve_y, curve_z = [], [], []

def build_curve_2D(start_x, start_y, control_x, control_y, end_x, end_y, resolution):

  curve_x.clear()
  curve_y.clear()
  
  control_line_x = []
  control_line_y = []
  guide_line_x = []
  guide_line_y = []
  
  curve_x.append(start_x)
  curve_y.append(start_y)
  
  for cycle in range(0,resolution):
    guide_line_x.append(start_x + ((control_x - start_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    guide_line_y.append(start_y + ((control_y - start_y)/resolution) * cycle)

    control_line_x.append(control_x + ((end_x - control_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    control_line_y.append(control_y + ((end_y - control_y)/resolution) * cycle)
    
  for points in range(0,resolution -1):
    curve_x.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_y[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_y[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_y[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_y[points+1]))[0])
    
    curve_y.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_y[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_y[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_y[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_y[points+1]))[1])
  curve_x.append(end_x)
  curve_y.append(end_y)

  return curve_x, curve_y

def build_curve_3D(start_x, start_y, start_z, control_x, control_y, control_z, end_x, end_y, end_z, resolution):
  
  curve_x.clear()
  curve_y.clear()
  curve_z.clear()

  curve_x.append(start_x)
  curve_y.append(start_y)
  curve_z.append(start_z)

  control_line_x = []
  control_line_y = []
  control_line_z = []
  guide_line_x = []
  guide_line_y = []
  guide_line_z = []

  for cycle in range(0,resolution):
    
    guide_line_x.append(start_x + ((control_x - start_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    guide_line_y.append(start_y + ((control_y - start_y)/resolution) * cycle)
    guide_line_z.append(start_z + ((control_z - start_z)/resolution) * cycle)
    
    control_line_x.append(control_x + ((end_x - control_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    control_line_y.append(control_y + ((end_y - control_y)/resolution) * cycle)
    control_line_z.append(control_z + ((end_z - control_z)/resolution) * cycle)

  for points in range(0,resolution -1):
    
    curve_x.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_y[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_y[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_y[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_y[points+1]))[0])
    
    curve_y.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_y[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_y[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_y[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_y[points+1]))[1])
    
    curve_z.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_z[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_z[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_z[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_z[points+1]))[1])
    
    
    
  curve_x.append(end_x)
  curve_y.append(end_y)
  curve_z.append(end_z)

  return curve_x, curve_y, curve_z
    
def __find__intersection__(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4):
  
  px = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
  py = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))

  return px , py


class test():
  def single_figure_test(curve,color):
    figure = plt.figure('single figure')
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.plot(curve[0],curve[1],curve[2],color)
    plt.show()

  def double_figure_test(curve_1,curve_2,color):
    figure = plt.figure('double figure')
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.plot(curve_1[0],curve_1[1],curve_1[2],color)
    ax.plot(curve_2[0],curve_2[1],curve_2[2],color)
    plt.show()

  def duplicate_test(curve_1,curve_2):
    for test in range(0,len(curve_1[0])):
      if curve_1[0][test] == curve_2[0][test]:
        print(curve_1[1][test],'- Duplicate Data Detected')
        
    for test in range(0,len(curve_1[1])):
      if curve_1[1][test] == curve_2[1][test]:
        print(curve_1[0][test],'- Duplicate Data Detected')
        
    for test in range(0,len(curve_1[2])):
      if curve_1[2][test] == curve_2[2][test]:
        print(curve_1[2][test],'- Duplicate Data Detected')
    print('Test Completed')
```

Comment: Getting rid of the global variables would likely help solve the issue. As an aside, how is the `test` class used? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @AMC the test class is used in the shell just to compare curves to each other it only temporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the curve lists (`curve_x, curve_y, curve_z = [], [], []`) inside the function and remove the global variables, you get different curves (but perhaps there was additional functionality I am missing).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def build_curve_3D(start_x, start_y, start_z, control_x, control_y, control_z, end_x, end_y, end_z, resolution):
  
  curve_x, curve_y, curve_z = [], [], []

  curve_x.append(start_x)
  curve_y.append(start_y)
  curve_z.append(start_z)

  control_line_x = []
  control_line_y = []
  control_line_z = []
  guide_line_x = []
  guide_line_y = []
  guide_line_z = []

  for cycle in range(0,resolution):
    
    guide_line_x.append(start_x + ((control_x - start_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    guide_line_y.append(start_y + ((control_y - start_y)/resolution) * cycle)
    guide_line_z.append(start_z + ((control_z - start_z)/resolution) * cycle)
    
    control_line_x.append(control_x + ((end_x - control_x)/resolution) * cycle)
    control_line_y.append(control_y + ((end_y - control_y)/resolution) * cycle)
    control_line_z.append(control_z + ((end_z - control_z)/resolution) * cycle)

  for points in range(0,resolution -1):
    
    curve_x.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_y[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_y[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_y[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_y[points+1]))[0])
    
    curve_y.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_y[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_y[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_y[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_y[points+1]))[1])
    
    curve_z.append((__find__intersection__(guide_line_x[points],guide_line_z[points],
                                           control_line_x[points],control_line_z[points],
                                           guide_line_x[points+1],guide_line_z[points+1],
                                           control_line_x[points+1],control_line_z[points+1]))[1])
    
    
    
  curve_x.append(end_x)
  curve_y.append(end_y)
  curve_z.append(end_z)

  return curve_x, curve_y, curve_z
    
def __find__intersection__(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4):
  
  px = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
  py = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))

  return px , py


curve_1 = build_curve_3D(0,10,10,2,4,6,5,8,9,10)
curve_2 = build_curve_3D(5,7,2,19,15,12,67,9,2,10)

curve_1 != curve_2
```

Note: For future posts include only necessary code for the minimal reproducible example